# pub global activate command - $HOME/.pub-cache/bin not on path

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-pub, dart-2

I was trying to install dart2 recently, but when I try to install `pub global activate stagehand`, it comes with a warning.

> Warning: Pub installs executables into `$HOME/.pub-cache/bin`, which is not on your path.

You can fix that by adding this to your shell's config file (`.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, etc.):

```
export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
```

so i went to my `.bash_profile` file and added the above, and the file looks like this:

```
export PATH=/users/kevinau/dart/flutter/bin:$PATH
export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
```

but then I run `webdev` and the command is still not found.

can anyone walk me thru how to fix this?

I tried echo `$PATH` and return the below:

```
/users/myspace/dart/flutter/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/sbin/.pub-cache/bin
```

but how do I fix it?

Comment: add export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin" in your terminal and execute your android studio termnial too. and restart the terminal.

Answer (score 74):

I have just run the following command in my cmd

```
export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
```

then I again run the command `dart pub global activate fvm` and the error is gone. In my case, I am having the error during installing fvm package.

Comment: run on terminal not worked. but run in vscode terminal is worked.

Comment: This is an easy solution on Mac. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Edit zshrc file using vim on terminal

```
vim ~/.zshrc
```

or

```
vim ~/.bashrc
```

edit data on zshrc after pressing "i" on keyboard.
Export flutter location, aqueduct location and dart sdk location

```
export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/Development/flutter/bin"
export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/bin"
export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/Development/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin"
```

After editing press "esc" key `~:wq` for saving
Check working of aqueduct using

```
aqueduct --version
```

or

```
aqueduct serve
```

Answer (score 5):

Add dart-sdk path to `.bash_profile`

```
export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/.pub-cache/bin"
```

Answer (score 5):

If you’re a mac user Just do the following:
In any system folder, you can go to home directory via command+shift+h
In home directory, you need to edit .bashrc file, but it’s hidden, use command+Shift+. To unhide.
Now, you can edit file and add this code to finish line:

```
export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
```

Congratulations your problem has been solved

Comment: on my system, the file in home directory i needed to edit was .zshrc  thnak you @Mohammad Hassan Farhadi for the directions on how to find it :)

Comment: I continued to have problems and after editing .zshrc I had to do a re-auth for my login see solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57941289/how-do-i-solve-error-failed-to-list-firebase-projects-see-firebase-debug-log

Answer (score 2):

### For Windows

Add `C:\flutter\.pub-cache\bin` into your system variable path

Comment: There is no bin folder located there

Answer (score 2):

For Unix-based system:

```bash
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.pub-cache/bin' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Use this after getting melos 'missing HOME path' ( for macOS users too)

Answer (score 1):

System Properties -> Environment variable -> System variable -> Path -> New -> $HOME/.pub-cache/bin

Answer (score 1):

I was setting my global environment variables after that warning on Window 10 pc but it was still giving me warning that your variable is not set even after I set all variables in environment variable settings

So I Simply restart my windows , it took some time for updating then after my pc starts. I ran this command "dart pub global activate protoc_plugin" and boom waning was gone

Sometimes windows do not get variables when they are set in present boot state so reloading boot (restarting windows) resolves the error

Answer (score 0):

For `webdev` you need also

```
pub global activate webdev
```

Comment: yes that too, both stagehand and webbed are both currently command not found

Comment: Do you have the Dart SDK installed? You can't use the Dart SDK included in Flutter for web development.

Comment: "and the command is still not found." is also not very helpful. Please add the full and exact error message to your question.

Comment: yes I have the Dart SDK installed, but how I do I differentiate Flutter's Dart SDK and Dart for Web SDK?.

Comment: When I type command webdev, it returns -bash: webdev: command not found

Comment: Is there a file `webdev` in `$HOME/.pub-cache/bin`? Did `pub global activate webdev` succeed or did it cause an error?

Comment: yes there are both webdev and stagehand in $HOME/.pub-cache/bin

Comment: looks like there is something wrong with `$HOME`. Your path `.../sbin:/sbin/.pub-cache/bin` should be `/sbin:/users/kevinau/.pub-cache/bin`. Also your path starts with `/users/myspace/dart/flutter/bin:` and as mentioned the `flutter` SDK doesn't work with web programming. Also in path you have `/users/myspace`, but in the command in your question you use `/users/kevinau/`.

Answer (score 0):

after install flutterfire global, my path in windows 10 will be :

```
C:\Users\Windows\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Its works for me...

```
export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for windows to find the path. Paste this in file explorer %LOCALAPPDATA%\Pub\Cache\bin