# How do I solve: Error: Failed to list Firebase projects. See firebase-debug.log for more info

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

So I'm minding my own business trying to initializing a Firebase project in my Angular app when all of the sudden I'm hit with this error:

```
Error: Failed to list Firebase projects. See firebase-debug.log for more info.
```

To get to that point, I followed the instructions in the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli) which are basically run:

```
$ npm install -g firebase-tools

$ firebase login // Turns out I was already logged in

$ firebase projects:list // Make sure you can access your account.
```

Anyway, back to the error. "Ok," I think. "I'll just check out the log it's pointing me to." I open the log and see:

```
HTTP Error: 401, Request had invalid authentication credentials. 
Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.
See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.`
`FirebaseError: HTTP Error: 401, Request had invalid authentication credentials.
Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.
See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.`
```

The part about "invalid authentication credentials" makes me think it has something to do with me not being logged into firebase but `firebase login` shows I am logged in.

The URL in the log just takes me to the docs for using firebase auth in my app. Well, I would love to. But first I need this command to work, Firebase.

Has anyone run into this/have a solution for it?

Comment: For flutter users: Naming with underscore was the only culprit.

Answer (score 757, accepted):

**Update**

The fix is:

```
firebase login --reauth
```

Thanks to @kynan in the comments for simplifying the original two-liner down to this one-liner.

If that doesn't work, you can also try logging out and logging back in like the original answer.

---

**Original Answer**

The fix is:

```
firebase logout
firebase login
```

It looks like when you upgrade firebase-tools, that may invalidate your auth token. You just have to log out and log back in.

Here's the message when you log out:

```
$ firebase logout
!  Invalid refresh token, did not need to deauthorize
+  Logged out from <email>
```

Comment: Alternative: `firebase login --reauth`

Comment: worked to me, $ firebase logout

$ firebase login

Comment: I tried but it's not working

Comment: The `firebase logout/login` is the better option in case you have many identities.

Answer (score 66):

For people who don't want to logout, the below command will also work.

> firebase login --reauth

Answer (score 22):

for Who don't want to logout, the below command also work

```
firebase login --reauth
```

First go to command prompt and run below code then execute above code.
In Command Prompt:

Run : `powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser`

Answer (score 9):

use `firebase logout` to log out 
then use `firebase login` to log back in to firebase in the CLI

Do this after updating the firebase tools using `npm install -g firebase-tools`

After succesfull login, use `firebase use --add` to list all the projects you have

Comment: The first 2 steps were okay in my own case. 'firebase use --add'  failed since I wasn't running from a Firebase project directory. So I opted for 'firebase projects:list' which worked like charm!. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I encountered Exact same error but for a different reason. I was configuring Flutter app for Both iOS and Android. My bundleId contained a `_` in it. so when I tried

```
flutterfire configure
```

Then my android app would configure just fine but iOS would not. and give this error. So if the above solution isn't working for you like me please check your `bundleId` or `package Name`. it can be the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

In my case that it couldn't list my firebase projects, I try to access firebase by vpn that I was installed on my system (not my browser), and it worked. Then I could initial firebase in my project as hosting and deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so for me it was the problem of the wifi I was using. Apparently the wifi had been denied access to firebase so I used vpn and it worked like charm. You can try using a vpn to see if it would come