# error: Failed to list Firebase projects. See firebase-debug.log for more info

Tags: firebase, npm, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I was tying to create firestore web app by following the link https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firestore-web#3
I came to 3rd lesson and I stuck at the below npm code
I have used firebase use --add
to list the projects.
I got the below error as firebase-console.log

```
 **[debug] [2021-03-04T08:25:39.308Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2021-03-04T08:25:39.312Z] Command:       C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\BKRK\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\bin\firebase.js use --add
[debug] [2021-03-04T08:25:39.312Z] CLI Version:   9.5.0
[debug] [2021-03-04T08:25:39.313Z] Platform:      win32
[debug] [2021-03-04T08:25:39.313Z] Node Version:  v12.18.0
[debug] [2021-03-04T08:25:39.315Z] Time:          Thu Mar 04 2021 13:55:39 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
[debug] [2021-03-04T08:25:39.315Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2021-03-04T08:25:39.316Z] 
[debug] [2021-03-04T08:25:39.328Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[debug] [2021-03-04T08:25:39.329Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
[debug] [2021-03-04T08:25:39.336Z] > refreshing access token with scopes: []
[debug] [2021-03-04T08:25:39.338Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token  
 <request body omitted>
[debug] [2021-03-04T08:25:42.275Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 400 {"expires":"Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT","date":"Thu, 04 Mar 2021 08:25:41 GMT","pragma":"no-cache","cache-control":"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","server":"scaffolding on HTTPServer2","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[debug] [2021-03-04T08:25:42.279Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects pageSize=1000
[debug] [2021-03-04T08:25:43.402Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects 401
[debug] [2021-03-04T08:25:43.403Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects [omitted]
[debug] [2021-03-04T08:25:43.403Z] HTTP Error: 401, Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
[debug] [2021-03-04T08:25:44.116Z] FirebaseError: HTTP Error: 401, Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
    at module.exports (C:\Users\BKRK\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\responseToError.js:38:12)
    at Client.doRequest (C:\Users\BKRK\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\apiv2.js:238:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async Client.request (C:\Users\BKRK\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\apiv2.js:96:20)
    at async getProjectPage (C:\Users\BKRK\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\management\projects.js:232:17)
    at async getFirebaseProjectPage (C:\Users\BKRK\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\management\projects.js:249:23)
    at async listFirebaseProjects (C:\Users\BKRK\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\management\projects.js:280:29)
[error] 
[error] Error: Failed to list Firebase projects. See firebase-debug.log for more info.**
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I solve: Error: Failed to list Firebase projects. See firebase-debug.log for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57941289/how-do-i-solve-error-failed-to-list-firebase-projects-see-firebase-debug-log)

Answer (score 5):

just type in the terminal

> firebase login --reauth

should open the browser and log in to your account again, it worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).