# FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Flutterfire just added a CLI for us to use, but I'm having a problem with the `flutterfire configure command`. I keep getting this error:

> i Found 0 Firebase projects. Selecting project liveasy-1.
> FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
> COMMAND: firebase --version
> ERROR: The FlutterFire CLI currently requires the official Firebase CLI to also be installed, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli for how to install it.

Even though I've installed the Firebase CLI and can run `firebase --version` without any issues. I installed the standalone binary and when that didn't work I installed it with npm as well. I can log in and see my projects list, but running `flutterfire configure` seems to be an issue. I can't also access any Firebase commands in Visual Studio Code.

Am I supposed to add something to the [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) in environmental variables? I've already added the cache/bin/ where flutterfire resides, but I don't know how to do the same for Firebase.

Comment: Do it actual contain *"An error [occured](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=occured) \[sic\]"*?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I went through the same issue on [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows). I figured out that installing Firebase CLI using the *binary file didn't work* for me (even after [Ventosus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70410843/firebasecommandexception-an-error-occured-on-the-firebase-cli-when-attempting-t/70417084#70417084)), so here is my answer.

I had to install the Firebase CLI using the npm command ([Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) is **required** to use this command):

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

I've then been able to run the command: `flutterfire configure`

Here is the documentation you have to follow in case you don't have Node.js or if you need any information: [Firebase CLI documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#windows-npm)

Comment: using the binary file didn't work for me either. I installed node.js as per this suggestion and the flutterfire configure worked fine.

Comment: will this be a problem to those who are unfamiliar with nodejs?

Comment: @Bensal you will find all the information you need with the link provided in my answer.

Comment: Didn't work for me (

Comment: Don’t forget to install nodejs first

Comment: The question does not state the usage of `nodeJS`. This is not a general answer

Answer (score 87):

Run:

```
firebase logout
```

Then:

```
firebase login
```

The issue is that your token expired.

Comment: I saw this in my log file but I was wondering why it will expire when I logged in less than 5 mins before running `flutterfire configure` command.

Comment: That is it. Tks!!!

Comment: this works for me

Comment: This error happend because of firebase credential expire. If you import code on github, always remember you need to logout firebase then login the firebase again to renew your credentials.

Answer (score 30):

For solving the standalone issue part of your question:

> **1** copy the downloaded .exe to your flutter project folder
>
> **2** rename it from firebase-tools-instant-win to just firebase (exe)
>
> **3** run "firebase login" from cmd line in the folder where you put the .exe and continue with flutterfire configure

This is a quick setup for a single project. If you plan to use Firebase CLI across multiple projects, you need to rename and move the .exe to a suitable location and fix environment/paths issues.

Comment: yes i did, and i had same issues as you had, i solve it in 45 seconds using above method. put the standalone in your flutter project folder, rename the standalone and flutterfire config will work

Comment: I did the above three steps and still getting the same error, I have logged in to the Firebase by downloading standalone using npm. My projects list shown in npm command but "flutterfire configure" didnt work. Any help will highly be appreciated.

Comment: the NPM is not the standalone they are referring to as well as the one i describe above.. the standalone is a the one found on the download page (look for: Download the Firebase CLI binary for Windows.) its a .exe fille named: firebase-tools-instant-win.exe which you could rename to firebase.exe and put it in your flutter project folder as described in my answer

Comment: I did, followed all three steps, renamed CLI binary to firebase.exe, but I wasn't able to run flutterfire configure command...

Comment: ok, that's strange.. worked for me.. did it twice now.. not sure exactly why that is. and you put it in your flutter project folder right? ran flutterfire command from same folder?

Comment: I did everything right but don't know what's the problem, I just solved the problem by Creating FirebaseOptions file and write code for that and added project in firebase console manually and it works. (You can copy FirebaseOptions file from a project where CLI worked and added that file in project and change credentials according to your project)

Comment: This worked but for some strange reason firebase configure doesnt work instead firebase config works

Answer (score 7):

For macOS users:

Enter `dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli` on your terminal.

It will successfully install `flutterfire_cli`, but with the warning:

The solution is to update the environment path.

Open terminal.

1. `vim ~/.zshrc`
2. Press the <kbd>I</kbd> key to activate insert mode.
3. Add -- `export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"`
4. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> then write `:wq` in the terminal and press enter to exit Vim.
5. Reopen the terminal and check `flutterfire --version`
6. `firebase login`
7. `flutterfire configure`

Comment: Make sure to close and reopen terminal window.

Answer (score 7):

It's fixed with me just by running the command:

`"firebase login --reauth"`

If your (Firebase debug log) contains a 401 error, then it just needs to be reauthorized.

To make sure that the this is the problem, run:

`firebase projects:list` 
and it will give you an error! then the solution is to reauthorize by the command above.

See: *[How do I solve: Error: Failed to list Firebase projects. See firebase-debug.log for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57941289/how-do-i-solve-error-failed-to-list-firebase-projects-see-firebase-debug-log)*

Answer (score 6):

Download the standalone binary for the CLI for Windows. It will download an executable, `firebase-tools-instant-win.exe`.

Copy it into your preferred location

The important part is to enter the path where the executable resides in the *Environment variables*:

*Environment variables* → *System variables* → *Path* → *New* → Enter the path

Launch the file and enter the necessary commands.

```
firebase login

dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli

cd [your project directory]
flutterfire configure
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It is still showing
```
i Found 0 Firebase projects.
FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
COMMAND: firebase --version 
ERROR: The FlutterFire CLI currently requires the official Firebase CLI to also be installed, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli for how to install it.
```

Answer (score 3):

For Windows users, make two CLI installations

*[Firebase CLI reference, Windows](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install-cli-windows)*

1. Windows installation. It has a GUI, which is good
2. npm installation - for the FlutterFire module to be recognized:

   `npm install -g firebase-tools`

Do not use Bash. Use the [cmd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) to execute FlutterFire commands.

Comment: when i try to run the windows version i get this error
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\snapshot\firepit\welcome.js:115:27)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:451:11)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:709:12)

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In case you run into another problem, especially this

```
Unhandled exception:
FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)...
```

After [Ventosus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70417084/8389687), check [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/invertase/flutterfire_cli/issues/27#issuecomment-1002768337) out. It helped me solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was that my authentication token was expired. As @DeePanShu pointed out, you should do

```
firebase logout && firebase login
```

But, if that's not the case, I highly recommend to read the file generated when the error happens (it will be saved in your app folder). There's a description of the problem, so you can avoid trying out solutions without knowing the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use the binary file from the official CLI website which is **firebase-tool-instant-win.exe** and naming it **firebase.exe**.

And then putting it in the Flutter project file that I am working on. It seems to do the trick.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are using the same Gmail account, signed in Firebase CLI and Firebase console.

Then Relogin into the Firebase CLI

1. Firebase logout
2. Firebase login

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was a case of **having a short name**. I wanted to create a project with the name **kwss**. This did not go through, but on changing the name to something else like **`hello_world`**, this worked and did not get the error again.

I'm not saying this is the solution, but it might work for someone's case.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly same issue

The solution that worked for me:

1. copy 'firebase-tools-instant-win.exe'. paste into your flutter project file, rename to 'firebase'.
2. run 'flutterfire configure' on the command line (others had error).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and tried everything I could. but npm method worked really well.
Install nodejs from https://nodejs.org/en/

this will also install npm to your system. then just run the command `npm install -g firebase-tools`

and you are good to use all firebase functions

All information I told I gained it from documentation. Developers best friend

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that helped me on Windows was just to use [Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio)'s built-in terminal.

PowerShell and the Firebase EXE file both throw different errors and wouldn't work.

I also used all the solutions mentioned here and there without any luck.

Comment: Didn't work for me (

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Firebase CLI with [npm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Npm_(software)) and still getting the error, try to restart your system and then try running the commands.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it works only in the command prompt (not PowerShell or the Node.js runtime): Microsoft Windows

Comment: THANK YOU
I do not know why I keep wasting my time with powershell

Comment: "command prompt" meaning [cmd.exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

In my case, it was the Node.js version. Try to do: `firebase --version` and if you have this message:

> Firebase CLI v11.17.0 is incompatible with Node.js v12.14.0 Please
> upgrade Node.js to version ^14.18.0 || >=16.4.0

Just upgrade your Node.js version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The binary file didn't work for me either. But I found another way that worked for me.

1. Go to the project's root.
2. Open the Command prompt.
3. Run `npm install -g firebase-tools`. (Make sure Node.js is installed)
4. There may be a couple of *WARN* deprecations, but never mind.
5. Then run `flutterfire configure`
6. You will be asked to select the project and the mobile versions you are willing to build.
7. Then make sure that a file was generated in 'lib\firebase_options.dart'

[See the link for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZrGV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all of the other answers, but there is the one solution that worked which makes sense (I'm so disappointed that I've forgotten about this).

My Flutter project path was inside of folders with symbols/spaces/uppercases in the name, once I've changed it, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For a Mac, run `flutterfire configure` as a superuser, hence run
`sudo flutterfire configure` in the terminal without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

### The Problem:

Flutter Cli needs two CLI supports (FlutterFire and Firebase), but here only FlutterFire is installed and added to your environment configuration. Firebase also needs Firebase cli.

### The Solution:

The solution is to add **C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm**. This path in your environment configuration, and then restart your [cmd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe), PowerShell, or [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code).

By this, you will let your system know that here is an executable file, which should run globally on your machine.

Comment: Why are you commenting on your own answer like this? Did you mean to do it from a different account?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to enable scripts to run by setting the PowerShell execution policy as this was preventing me from running scripts.

Open PowerShell as an administrator
Run the command: Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser

Answer (score 0):

i had your same problem but when i run this command

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

in cmd the problem solved
but note to run it in cmd not CLI , when you run it in ClI you will get warns and errors

Answer (score 0):

This is some of solutions I have tried

- Try login/logout
- Try to create project manual way in firebase website
- Try with different project id

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve this issue you need to make sure that first download  **Firebase CLI binary for Windows** (**not** standalone cli).

[image]

[image]

Now copy that **firebase-tools-instant-win** file into your project folder.
And rename it to **firebase**.

Now open that **firebase-tools-instant-win** in **downloads folder** and be ready to type command.

1. cd <path_of_your_project>
2. firebase login
3. dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
4. flutterfire configure

The reason that you were getting error because your **firebase-tools-instant-win** in downloads folder were unable to find cli named "**firebase**" so we are putting it by copying it from downloads folder.

Answer (score 0):

For me I just added `firebase_core` plugin to pubspec.yaml, run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`, and rerun the `flutterfire configure ...` command and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's JDK Path Problem you need to add Java JDK do the following seps:

1-Add JDK path to your user variables as example C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2\bin.
2-then restart your terminal and try again flutterfire configur command.
it work with me.

Answer (score 0):

> Firebase CLI v13.3.0 is incompatible with Node.js v16.20.0 Please upgrade Node.js to version >=18.0.0 || >=20.0.0

In my case I just had to use **higher** node.js version.

```
nvm use 18
```

was solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried different available solution using both standalone binary,
> npm, logout/login none of them have worked for me...

**I solved the problem by running the cmd on the windows 11 powershell instead of the VS code terminal.**

used OS:windows 11

Answer (score 0):

**In FLUTTER** [**March 2024**].

I added Firebase with the command 'flutterfire configure --project=PROJECT`, Then I scheduled the Android app in Firebase to delete which was preventing me from rerunning this command till I restored the app, and the command worked smoothly.

You can check your deletion scheduled apps under:
Firebase console > Project settings > Your apps > pending deletion apps (LEFT PANE) click the app whose package you want to use and restore.

Answer (score -1):

Do not waste your time by login/logout. It happens when your project **limits** have been reached. **Add new accounts**, and **deleting projects will require 30 days** to get effective. So the best solution is to add a new account but log out current account.

Answer (score -2):

delete `C:\Users\USERNAME.cache\firebase`

Run `firebase-win-exe`

Authentication process will start you press Y

Allow Firebase to collect CLI and Emulator Suite usage and error reporting information? Y

Copy a google link and paste it into browser and Log into your google account to allow access to firebase

Success! Logged in as tahira6020@gmail.com

[image]