# FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm having a problem with the flutterfire configure command. I keep getting this error:

[image]

i try this
[2](https://github.com/invertase/flutterfire_cli/issues/27#issuecomment-1002768337): [FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70410843/firebasecommandexception-an-error-occured-on-the-firebase-cli-when-attempting-t) and this [enter link description here](https://github.com/invertase/flutterfire_cli/issues/27#issuecomment-1002768337)

and i did `firebase logout` then `firebase login` and this error is still the same what should i do?

[image]

Comment: Did you try `firebase init` after `firebase login` command?

Comment: i use it now but still the same error

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error: in my case it was just the outdated version of Node.js.
Updating Node to a version greater or equal than 14.8.0 solved the problem. Download the latest stable version from [Node website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) for Windows or run

```
npm install -n g
```

for MacOs and Linux.