# CLI Problems - firebase

Tags: flutter, android-studio, command-line-interface

I am trying to connect firebase to android studio and keep getting errors. The firebase_core and firebase_auth are already installed but when I try to configure CLI and enter `flutterfire` configure then this error occurs.
What is git? what does he want me to do?
CLI has already been updated three times, why does it say it would be the wrong version? If more info is needed please let me know and don't just close the question.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYnzl.png)

Comment: Seems like you are missing git, [install it as described here](https://github.com/git-guides/install-git) and try again.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70410843/firebasecommandexception-an-error-occured-on-the-firebase-cli-when-attempting-t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70410843/firebasecommandexception-an-error-occured-on-the-firebase-cli-when-attempting-t)