# i Found 0 Firebase projects. FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-tools

i Found 0 Firebase projects.
FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.

this error occurred. everything completed cli. flutter --version command and everything run perfectly, but thjs error occurred when run **flutterfire **configure in android studio

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70410843/firebasecommandexception-an-error-occured-on-the-firebase-cli-when-attempting-t

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70410843/firebasecommandexception-an-error-occured-on-the-firebase-cli-when-attempting-t)

Comment: no its not working to me