# Pub is not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: flutter, dart

im trying to install the `get_cli` package for flutter.

install command is `pub global activate get_cli`, however pub is not a global variable on my windows 10 machine.

i think i need to add variables to the `system environment variables`, but i'm not sure what paths and how to call them.

this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62643448/13454563) works for unix, so im looking for something similar for windows.

anyone got an idea?

edit: error: `'pub' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you have Flutter in `C:\src\flutter`, you can add path variable: `C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin` (if you have Flutter in another localization, just replace the beginning of the path analogically) and restart your command line tool (or IDE).

You can add `flutter` prefix before `pub` as well: `flutter pub global activate get_cli` - according to `flutter -h`:

> `flutter pub` - pass the remaining arguments to Dart's "pub" tool

Comment: thank you very much. i already have added the flutter before, so all i needed to do was add flutter before the pub keyword.

Comment: there is name and value column, value is the path, does name matter or is it only for me so i know in the future when i forget?

Comment: Name is used by an app or system and is pre-defined. For example: [Widows environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows), [Dart environment variables](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/environment-variables) or [Android Studio environment variables](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables#envar). You should define Dart path in `User variables` -> `Path` (there you can set only paths). Do not confuse it with `System variables`.

Answer (score 9):

Use `dart pub` not `pub` only and it should resolve your problem

enjoy

Answer (score 2):

use `flutter pub` and make sure the path variable is `C:\flutter\bin` supposing the Flutter folder is located at `C:\flutter`

Answer (score -1):

make sure you set the environment variables correctly.After that don't forget to restart the computer. I struggled with this issue for a long time but after doing all these things a magic code worked for me . Which you guys can also try.

**dart pub global activate get_cli**
then use
**flutter pub global activate get_cli**

this should work .