# Why does the choco add the path that not exist in my computer when install dart?

Tags: dart

I installed dart by `choco install dart-sdk`.
When choco adds any path in the PATH environment variable, I will check this.
In my case, the choco said `PATH environment variable does not have C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\bin in it. Adding...` and the choco adds this in my path environment variable. But my computer doesn't have `Pub\Cache\bin` in the `Roaming` folder!?

Is this normal? Why does the choco add this path in the path environment variable? Should I delete this path from the PATH environment variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pub global activate command - $HOME/.pub-cache/bin not on path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52794266/pub-global-activate-command-home-pub-cache-bin-not-on-path)  And the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70693653/724039

Comment: I think not. I edited my question to be easier to explain.

Comment: see: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-cache    If is the directory used by `dart pub cache ....`. This directory is empty after install, which seems logical. (I do not have enough knowledge about dart to explain more)

Comment: oops, cache is in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Pub\Cache`, not in `%APPDATA%\Pub\Cache`

Comment: [pub uses %APPDATA% and not %LOCALAPPDATA% #22954](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/22954) and [pub uses %APPDATA% and not %LOCALAPPDATA% #1273](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/1273)

Comment: But question is off-topic, because it's not about programming. Also choco has nothing to do (should have nothing to do) with install of `dart`. Managing PATH is an OS issue.

Comment: What do you think about this? Should I delete this path from the PATH environment variable or let this stay here?

Comment: Ask your systemadministrator , and do not be wondered when your dart application is failing when it tries to use that folder.  This is beside the fact that it seems to have been defined wrong in the past (see the 2 github links in my earlier comment)